# syntax error when passing php variables to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I know that there're already a few questions asking about passing php variables to javascript. I looked at these questions and finally it leads me to one most popular answer. It suggests a very simple way to use php variables in javascript as below:

```
1  <script>    
2       var data =<?php echo json_encode("42");?>;
3       //Don't forget the extra semicolon!
4  </script>
```

In sublime, line 2 is indicated as an error.

I tried to either put the code in a .js file, or in a .php file with script tag. Both ways give me syntax errors. But it seems that others using this answer don't have this problem. I'm a beginner in web development and this may be some basic thing. But I really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I would assume that your editor simply can't handle multiple lanugages in the same file. It looks like you are editing an HTML file that now contains both JavaScript and PHP. Perhaps this is the issue. Can you tell which language it thinks the error is in? Is the issue with the JS code? With the PHP code?

Comment: when you view the resulting source code what do you see? right click your running webpage and click View Source. You can then see what the PHP evaluates to (if it does evaluate of course)...understand that what runs on the client (JS) and the server (PHP)...so when you view the page source you should NEVER see raw PHP code

Comment: simple PHP can't run in .js file and if you are going to execute php in .js file should change settings

Comment: can you write the Error that php shows you?

Comment: I think the issue is with the PHP part. This is a simple test. My original js code will create a <p> tag in the current page, and I want to obtain the username from the php session variable and use it as the content the the p tag. I tested the js code by simply let the p tag shows "welcome", it works. But once I use the above php tag to get access to the session variable, it fails.

Comment: It didn't show me any error information. It just indicates the line as an error by putting a red dot.  Briefly, I have another php file login.php that stores a session variable. And I run the entire thing in MAMP, it fails to obtain the session variable I want and display it

Comment: I understand that sensitive information shouldn't be placed in script. So I did use a separate login.php which receives and check username and password. Here I just want to get access to the username after the user log in.

Comment: var data = "<?php echo json_encode("42");?>";